# Problems loading a vue module in a micro-frontend application

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-component

I am quite new to VUE but trying to apply the best-practices I learned in various other frontend technologies to that. One of them being a micro-frontend approach.
So far I was able load my module dynamically, but when it comes to dynamically adding the routes for my micro-apps to the router I am having this problem.

As long as I do this:

```js
router.addRoute("root", {
    path: '/' + frontendModule.name.toLowerCase(),
    name: frontendModule.name,
    component: () => import(frontendModule.url),
    meta: { title: frontendModule.name }
})
```

It doesn't seem to work and I'm getting "Failed to resolve module specifier 'module-web-cli/App'".

But if I change the code to this:

```js
router.addRoute("root", {
    path: '/' + frontendModule.name.toLowerCase(),
    name: frontendModule.name,
    component: () => import("module-web-cli/App"),
    meta: { title: frontendModule.name }
})
```

It seems to work. However the value of "frontendModule.url" is exactly "module-web-cli/APP".

Comment: If import was a function I would not believe this, but import is a "function-like expression" according to [mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/import). That being said, I still don't know why this would happen.

Comment: are you sure there is nothing else happening here?

Comment: I also am starting to think that this is actually not implemented as a real function, but as some sort of syntactic sugar, that the compiler interprets. 
In above case I've built and deployed the application twice ... ones with the variable, then I get the error and once with the constant string and then it works.
If this is just syntactic-sugar for the compiler ... is there a way to achieve what I am trying to do? I mean ... even when using the constant string, the compiler has no type information on the web-module-cli/App type ... just a promise that it exists.

Comment: I interpret the documentation-link I posted in a way that your code would be allowed. Also, if a dynamic import statement would only allow string constants, why would it even exist? The only idea I have is that `frontendModule.url` is something more complex than a string. Can you `console.log(typeof frontendModule.url)`?

Comment: Having a look at this document: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/import ... specially it seems the last chapter seems to be handling the case of a variable as import ...  there they do things differently ... I'll try to see if I can apply this to my case.

Comment: all that `\`${x}\` ` does is turn x into a string, that should not be necessary if `x` is already a string.

Comment: The "typeof frontendModule.url" logged "string" for every occurrence.

Answer (score 0):

As you think,the compiler help you to transform "module-web-cli/App" to "./module-web-cli/App.vue" when the path is a constant  string,but wont do that when the path is a variable, you can resolve by changing frontendModule.url, like this './module-web-cli/App.vue'

Comment: I could imagine this works, if App.vue was in the same Vue project ... however this is build in a completely separate module and simply deployed on the same server.

Comment: I have made some progress, by passing a fully qualified url to the import function ... so if I send "http://localhost:8080/assets/module-web-cli.js" i can see it successfully loading the module-web-cli.js and the preloader js thingy that this requires. However in this case I don't "instantiate" the exported "App" type the js file provides and I'm getting another error: "Couldn't resolve component "default" at "/cli""

Comment: which "compiler" are you referring to? Javascript or Typescript themselves don't do that. Neither should something like babel or webpack do that. Do you think vue does that on some level?

Answer (score 0):

So with quite a bit of help from my colleagues, we managed to get it working:

So the addition of the route is done like this:

```
        router.addRoute("root", {path: '/' + frontendModule.name.toLowerCase(), name: frontendModule.name, component: () => import(axios.defaults.baseURL + "assets/module-" +  frontendModule.url + ".js").then(value => value.App), meta: { title: frontendModule.name}})
```

The important part seems to be the ".then(value => value.App)" which seems to instantiate the "App" type contained inside the loaded javascript.

But we also completely changed the configuration of the modules vite config.

The host application now has this:

```
export default defineConfig({
  build: {
    target: 'esnext',
    rollupOptions: {
      external: ["vue"],
      output: {
        globals: {
          vue: "Vue",
        },
      },
    },
  },
  server: {
    port: 8085
  },
  plugins: [
    vue(),
    vueJsx(),
  ],
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      '@': fileURLToPath(new URL('./src', import.meta.url))
    }
  }
})
```

The config of the dynamically loaded module is this:

```
export default defineConfig({
  define: { "process.env.NODE_ENV": '"production"' },
  build: {
    target: "esnext",
    lib: {
      entry: resolve(__dirname, "./src/lib.ts"),
      name: "CLI",
      fileName: "module-web-cli",
    },
    rollupOptions: {
      external: ["vue"],
      output: {
        globals: {
          vue: "Vue",
        },
      },
    },
  },
  plugins: [vue(), vueJsx()],
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      "@": fileURLToPath(new URL("./src", import.meta.url)),
    },
  },
});
```

And the index.html needed a modulemap to tell it where to load vue from:

```
<script type="importmap">
  {
    "imports": {
      "vue": "./vue.runtime.esm-browser.prod.js"
    }
  }
</script>
```

At least with this config I am now able to dynamically load my modules.

Comment: did you find out what was wrong with the original code and why the strange behaviour of variables vs literals appeared?

Comment: Admittedly not ... I am quite new to Vue and it seems most information available on the web is more of a type: "If you want X do Y" and don't really provide much explanation. To me most config files involved are a bit of a mystery. I was happy my colleague was able to help, but I can't explain what the original problem was. I was just happy it's working now and thought I'd share it here (even if it just adds more to the "If A then B" type of information. Sorry.

Comment: Too bad, I was hoping to learn about a new footgun.